# How to display malayalam font in blackberry 5<?

Tags: blackberry

I am developing a blackberry 7 native java sdk. it should support malayalam font.
What should i do for this... Please guide me.
When i try to show some malayalam text it shows some other string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to confirm, you are doing this for OS's 5 and later.  It is not possible to add fonts before OS 5.

Here are the instructions for doing this in OS 5.0.

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Load_and_use_a_custom_font_899948_11.jsp

The same instructions apply to later OS's.  The main difference with later OS's is that the size of the font is not so restricted. In OS 5.0 the font must be either less than 60K or less than 90K depending on how you load it.

You will find a different approach being used in this sample code:

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Font-Loader-Manager-Utility/m-p/592647#M122351